# Static dispatch in Pascal

Tags: freepascal

I have a simple class hierarchy of boxes like this:

```
type
  Box = object

    (* v := value; *)
    constructor Init(value: integer);

    (* WriteLn('this box contains a ', v); *)
    procedure Describe; virtual;

    protected
    var v: integer;

  end;

  SpecialBox = object(Box)

    (* implementation sets value and otherValue *)
    constructor Init(value: integer, otherValue: integer);

    (*  WriteLn('this special box contains ', v, ' and ', v2); *)
    procedure Describe; virtual;

    protected
    var v2: integer;

  end;
```

I left out the (trivial) implementations because I don't want to clutter the question with the verbose syntax of Pascal. Anyway, I have the following procedure:

```
procedure printBox(box: Box); begin
  box.Describe;
end;
```

Note that the procedure uses a statically allocated `Box`. From languages like C++ I would expect the call `box.Describe` to be linked statically to the method in the `Box` class. Instead, the result I am seeing in the console is

```
'this special box contains <the value of v> and <garbage because v2 is sliced off>'
```

Hence my question: Does Pascal (or FPC in particular) employ other strategies with regards to method dispatch?

Comment: This is classic slicing as you see in C++. It's one of many reasons why we don't use `object` in Delphi. You should know that `object` has been obsolete for a couple of decades now. Use `class` instead. Note also that in the derived class you need to use `override` to override a virtual method. Finally, why did you tag the question delphi and then refer to fpc? It is usually important to know what language you are coding in.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sadly the university I attend doesn't care about the fact that this has been deprecated for ages. :-) I was asking specifically for the reasons of this strange behavior. The thing about the language is that we used to do Turbo Pascal but for the sake of learning OOP we used object-pascal (i think?). And since lots of threads on the web seem to mix up Pascal and Delphi I figured I might find someone who can help me here by using the Delphi tag as well.

Comment: It's important that we know what language you are using. Pascal is actually many different flavours. With fpc there are different modes. Knowing which mode you use is important. Question should be tagged freepascal. Have a read about object slicing, that will set you straight.

Comment: Do note that FreePascal has several syntax differences . In fact in order to successfully compile Delphi code in FreePascal you need to enable [Delphi mode](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse74.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu27.html):

"For objects, it is sufficient to redeclare the same method in a descendent object with the keyword virtual to override it"

which is exactly what you're doing. So your Describe method is dispatched dynamically, despite the Box object is allocated statically (the two are not ra. If you want it to be dispatched statically, then don't use virtual methods.